# what is the good data structure for KV pair searching. (more details in post)

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, data-structures

I have very big KV pari file such as

```
[key]: [value]
 word2: value2 
word3: value3 
... 
helloworldyou: hiworld
```

I want to implement an efficient algorithm by using right datastrcutre to do this:

By typing "world". it shows all KV pairs that Key contains "world"

I thought about TRIE, but i know it is good for dictionary search. Not so much match my case.
Or which java or cpp library is good for this?
Need help ,thanks.

Comment: have you tried [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) ?

Comment: @qqibrow this requires me knowing suffix, which is not my case.

Comment: why you don't know the suffix? if you have the word, you know the suffix. Given a word lenth n, build suffix tree is O(n), and search for a substr with length m is O(m).

Comment: @BufBills - generalized suffix tree or suffix list lets you do an indexed search of any substring; look for all suffixes that start with the substring.  Might check this wikipedia page which has links to additional full-text search techniques: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array

Comment: A generalized suffix array or compressed suffix tree is exactly what you want. Try [libdivsufsort](https://code.google.com/p/libdivsufsort/).